# reorder row in uiitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my application, i want the users to reorder the contents of the differnt rows as well as to delete the rows they wish to. How to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check these tutorials, they explain it pretty good!

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=95195

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/